# Show not working from OnClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a javascript `function Display(args...)` that modifies the content of a modal window depending on which button is pressed. The function contains other attributes that are hidden or displayed (depending on the arguments that are being passed). Where I am going crazy is that a particular div section refuses to hide/display. Let's say that initially I set it up to be hidden/display:none, then onClick is suppose to be display it; even if I invert the initial state the expected behavior does not occur. I set up the debugger and I see that is trying:

```
if ($('#SectionRefusingToShow').is(":visible") == false) {
   $('#SectionRefusingToShow').show();
}
```

I see it enters the if statement but still not shown. Inspecting the DOM, its element attribute `display:none` was not removed. For other classes and ids the hidden are properly removed/added. I am using .show for this one given that hidden state for it did not work either!

Comment: Can you give some code? I tried it on JSFiddle and it's working well. https://jsfiddle.net/hd38dkxt/1/ . Have I understood you?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. We can't help when we can't reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem before, and it turned out that I had multiple elements with the same ID value. Have you checked for that? jQuery can get a little fussy when you select elements by ID, and the ID is not unique (which is technically invalid, so it get's fussy for a good reason).